# Text shows up dim (initially) when trying to make a gallery of layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, gallery, android-view

I am trying to make a gallery that functions similar to the android market where you can scroll (left/right) to view free or paid apps and etc... Also be able to scroll up and down through a layout.

So far I just have it loading two layouts that have a simple "Hello World!" text view and a "Hey! how are you?" text view.

They load fine, except initially the text at position 0 of the gallery shows up dim until I scroll away and back to it. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
public class HelloGallery extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Gallery gallery = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter(this));

        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {
                Toast.makeText(HelloGallery.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}


public class ViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public Context mContext;
    public static final Integer[] viewId = { R.layout.helloworld, R.layout.heyhowareyou };
    public int mGalleryItemBackground;

    public ViewAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        TypedArray attr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        attr.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return viewId.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(viewId[position], null);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I also referenced this a little bit. What Aavon in this thread is doing is exactly what I'm trying to get at...

Thread Link: [Get button to work in gallery with inflated layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020707/get-button-to-work-in-gallery-with-inflated-layouts)

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my layout xml, I found that I wasn't setting the color for the text that was appearing on the screen. When I set that color, the text no longer dims out when loading the layout.